# Chrome web store css layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout

I saw the chrome web store and would like to know how they create the css layout like that. I mean how to create the layout with fix size pixels left panel and flexible fluid layout when you re-size the browser. Can the grid css framework archive the same result?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Thank you.

Comment: You could use any grid (example, foundation,  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/25/rapid-prototyping-for-any-device-with-foundation/ )

Comment: The grid css framework? Which grid css framework? Most do, [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) does.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a fixed `width` for the left panel and a variable `width` for the right panel along with media-queries.

Media queries allow you to replace a .CSS with another when the viewport = defined size or other variables.

Be sure to check this out for further information on how to use media queries for your specific needs: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html